# MissingFieldException (AmbientTransactionWarning) using EF Core in Revit addin

Tags: c#, revit-api, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I'm using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (3.1.1) to save some data to MySql. When the context is first configured I'm getting this exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.MissingFieldException' in Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.dll
>
> Field not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalEventId.AmbientTransactionWarning'

Here's my `OnConfiguring`:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        // This works just fine, even though that type is then not available in `UseMySql`.
        var test = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalEventId.AmbientTransactionWarning; 

        // Exception thrown here.
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=localhost;database=test;uid=user;pwd=<password>;TreatTinyAsBoolean=true;", x => x.ServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 29), ServerType.MySql)); 
    }
}
```

Possible complicating factor: The app is an addin for Autodesk Revit. I've had some dll loading issues which I believe I've worked out, but it is a non-standard environment which could be causing issues. I've verified that `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`, the dll that provides `AmbientTransactionWarning`, is loaded when `UseMySql` is called. Also, while VS is paused on the exception, if I enter `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalEventId.AmbientTransactionWarning` in the Immediate window, I don't get an error. I also have another stand-alone WPF app that uses the same database model and DbContext object, which communicates with the database just fine.

I'm not sure how to proceed in debugging this. Thanks!

**Edit**

Both the addin and Revit (2020) are using .NET Framework 4.7.2.

**Stacktrace:**

```
Field not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalEventId.AmbientTransactionWarning'.

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlDbContextOptionsExtensions.ConfigureWarnings(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseMySql(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 mySqlOptionsAction)

   at <MyAssembly>.DatabaseContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
```

**Library Loading**

Typically Revit addins load their dependencies automatically as needed. Occasionally not, though, so I have added the following resolver which manually loads assemblies which in past runs have failed to load automatically:

```
    // Executed on first run of addin.
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveMissingAssemblies;

...

private System.Reflection.Assembly ResolveMissingAssemblies(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string[] dlls = new[]
    {
        "System.Memory",
        "System.Buffers",
        "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions",
        "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore",
        "MySqlConnector",
    };

    string dll = dlls.FirstOrDefault(name => args.Name.Contains(name));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dll))
    {
        string filename = Path.Combine(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
            $"{dll}.dll");

        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(filename);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The more I look at this the more it seems that somehow the field in question is available in my main assembly but not in EntityFrameworkCore. I'm not sure why or how that would be the case. I've also tried using IlMerge to combine various parts of the addin, but haven't been able to get anything working in that direction.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Also, please add which version of .NET Framework or .NET Core you are using for your addin. You might also want to share your assembly resolution code of your addin, that you are likely to use to ensure that the needed assemblies can be found and loaded.

Comment: @lauxjpn Done. Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Ah, Revit is using .NET Framework as well. I just saw on the Wikipedia article, that its initial release was in 2000, so I assumed that it is probably a C++ application and your addin is a .NET assembly anyway (which is possible). That setup usually needs some assembly resolution plumbing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely an issue in resolving dependent assemblies.

You probably want to debug your `ResolveMissingAssemblies()` method (or log all assemblies that your event handler is unable to resolve).

Also output/take a look at the `ResolveEventArgs.RequestingAssembly` property, that tells you what assembly the current one is a dependency of (to understand the dependency tree).

The `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` assembly e.g. depends on `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, which depends on 10 other libraries (some of which depend on other libraries again).

A simple way to ensure they are all being loaded, is to make your event handler a bit more generic:

```cs
private System.Reflection.Assembly ResolveMissingAssemblies(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string filename = Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
        $"{args.Name}.dll");

    return File.Exists(filename))
        ? System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(filename)
        : null;
}
```

Comment: Success!! Making the event handler more generic fixed it. I never got assembly loading errors, and the field loaded ok in my main assembly, so I didn't think this was the issue. Thanks for your help!